# Can't get element below fixed div to show full height with paddings or margins

Tags: css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rg3w8kxc/2/

I have a fixed bar on top and an element below it. Since the top bar is fixed, I need to add some padding to the top of the element below it so that the whole height of that element shows. However, when I add something like `padding-top:40px` for example, it doesn't move the element down; rather it creates space below the element. Same goes with `margin`.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. What's the issue here?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="top-bar">
        <div class="section-wrap">
            <a href="/">Win a [name of phone]!</a>
        </div><!-- .section-wrap -->
    </div>

<div id="top-section-page">
        <div class="section-wrap">
            <a href="/"><span>⇦</span> Back to the mix</a>
        </div>
</div>
<p>Some text here</p>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#top-bar {
  background: #FAFAFA;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

#top-section-page {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/KNYV8j2.jpg") repeat center top #69C9CA;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #FFF;
  line-height: 185px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add add the padding-top on the body and then you need a top 0px on the #top-bar

Add this to your css code:

```
body{
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#top-bar {
    top: 0px;
}
```